# Refresh Identity authentification cookie to avoid logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, session-cookies

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application with Identity to manage the users connections.

I have some custom Manager, Store and Providers for the need of my application :

```
services.AddIdentity<Utilisateur, Profil>().AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<Utilisateur>>().AddRoleManager<CustomRoleManager>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<Utilisateur>, UserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Profil>, ProfileStore>();
services.AddTransient<IPermissionProvider, PermissionProvider>();
```

I have set up the application cookie for the Identity authentification :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

And

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults the path to /Account/Login.
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Connexion/Login");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Connexion/SignedOut");
            // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Connexion/AccessDenied");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

The problem is that the user is automatically disconnected after 30 minutes even if he is not idle and uses the application at this moment.

How can I refresh or recreate the authentification cookie to avoid this problem ?

I tried to create a method to refresh the cookie but it doesn't seem to work very well... The user is disconnected even with this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RefreshLogin]
    [RequiresPermission("Pages.Modification")]
    public IActionResult SavePagesOrder() 
    {...}
```

and the method :

```
public class RefreshLoginAttribute : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await context.HttpContext.RefreshLoginAsync();

        await next();
    }
}
```

Have you an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution I used with IdentityServer 4. Sorry, it may be messy but I hope you grasp the point. Here every time you validate principal you could rewrite your access and refresh token into cookies.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
                        {
                            var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                            var timeElapsed = now.Subtract(x.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value);
                            var timeRemaining = x.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.Subtract(now);

                            if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
                            {
                                var discoveryResponse = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(gatewaySettings.IdentitySeverAddress);
                                if (discoveryResponse.IsError)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception(discoveryResponse.Error);
                                }

                                var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) x.Principal.Identity;
                                var accessTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst("access_token");
                                var refreshTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst("refresh_token");

                                var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint, "MyApi", "secret");

                                var refreshToken = refreshTokenClaim.Value;

                                var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);

                                if (!tokenResponse.IsError)
                                {
                                    identity.RemoveClaim(accessTokenClaim);
                                    identity.RemoveClaim(refreshTokenClaim);

                                    identity.AddClaims(new[]
                                    {
                                        new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken),
                                        new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken)
                                    });
                                    x.ShouldRenew = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                })
```

May be it somehow helps you.

Comment: Yes it seems to be a good idea to solve my problem. However I don't have IdentiyServer so Visual Studio cannot find DiscoveryClient and TokenClient.
With your solution I tried something like `if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
                            {
                                await x.HttpContext.RefreshLoginAsync();
                            }`
I don't know if it will work but I will test it like this.

Comment: You may use what you want to reissue token. IdentityServer is just one of variants.